# Traveling Asia & need to switch to my other passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, asia

I haven two passports (US & Irish). I'm currently traveling on my US passport but it's getting full & want to switch to my Irish passport so I will be able to get a visa when in Indonesia. Will I have any problems at immigration? Should I just stay in Malaysia and get another American passport?

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel although I am not voting this as a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem to "switch" passports during your travels. The only rule is to make sure you *leave* a country with the same passport you *entered* with.

I don't know if Malaysia has exit passport control, but if they do, show them your US one when you leave, so they know you left. When you enter Indonesia, show them your Irish passport.